# How can I deal with completely missing data in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code returns

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

due to the `miss` column not having any data. This seems to imply that one of the axes becomes discrete (which is incorrect) and hence does not accept numerical values.

How can I prevent this axis from becoming discrete?

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), c(NA, NA, NA))
colnames(data) <- c("x", "y", "miss")


plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous() + 
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y - 1, ymax = y + 1)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = miss, xmax = miss, ymin = miss, ymax = miss))

print(plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a vector like `data$miss` and fill only with `NA` values, the type is defaulted to a `"logical"` class.  Effectively, it's the same when you create an empty vector too.

```
> class(vector())
[1] "logical"
```

If you remove your plot code line-by-line, you can see the issue is with the `geom_rect()` line, which now makes sense:  you are asking your aesthetics to be assigned to a logical value (`data$miss`), not a numeric value.

To fix, just let R know that `data$miss` is numeric:

```
data$miss <- as.numeric(data$miss)
```

That fixes your issue and the plot works fine - you will just get the following Warning message and will obviously not be able to see the rect geom:

```
Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

Comment: "the type is defaulted to a `logical` class" - this is the information that I was missing, thank you! I had already been playing around with `as.numeric` on the first two columns, but not on the `NA` one.